# jQuery dialog popup returns Json to new page instead of current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application and I'm trying to insert properties of certain objects. For that, I made a modal popup via jQuery dialog. I don't want it interfering with other actions that the user is doing, so I made an Ajax.BeginForm. I hoped that when I do the insert, it will close on return PartialView(), but it opens the popup View on full screen instead of closing the dialog. A friend suggested to return Json, but still it returns it on the popup url (/AddDept) instead of returning it to the current url (without reloading).

It is crucial that the base view should be dynamic, so you can open the dialog on any page and not make a reload on submit.

I've read the other similar issues and couldn't resolve my problem.

Please, help me to achieve the proper function if possible. Code below:

JS:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = "";
                $("#dialog-alert").dialog({
                    title: 'Error encountered!',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 350,
                    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true
                });

                if ('@TempData["msg"]' != "") {
                    $("#dialog-alert").dialog('open');
                }

                $("#lnkServer").on("click", function (e) {
                    url = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('#dialog-edit').dialog({ title: "Add a new Server" });
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                $("#lnkIssType").on("click", function (e) {
                    url = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('#dialog-edit').dialog({ title: "Add a new Issue Type" });
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                $("#lnkUser").on("click", function (e) {
                    url = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('#dialog-edit').dialog({ title: "Add a new User" });
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                $("#lnkDept").on("click", function (e) {
                    url = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('#dialog-edit').dialog({ title: "Add a new Department" });
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 400,
                    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        //$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                        $(this).load(url);
                    }
                    //buttons: {
                    //    "Cancel": function () {
                    //        $(this).dialog("close");
                    //    }
                    //}
                });
            });

        function onSuccess() {
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
        }
    </script>
```

Form:

```
<div id="container">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddDept", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department_Name)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Department_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line input-properties", placeholder = "Collections" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department_Name)
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-add-properties" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddDept([Bind(Include = "Department_Name")] Department @dept)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Departments.Add(@dept);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    TempData["Msg"] = "Data has been saved successfully";
                    return Json(TempData["Msg"]);
                    //return Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                TempData["Msg"] = "Probably the record already exists. If not, contact Georgi Georgiev, RA Dept.";
                return Json(TempData["Msg"]);
            }
            return Json(@dept);
            }
```

Comment: It means that you have not included `jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js` in the view or layout, or its not loaded correctly

Comment: Probably, but I've already added an ajax.post method which solved the problem.

Comment: That's a far better solution anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was probably due to that my Ajax.BeginForm popup View relied on different ActionResult in the controller compared to the Background View's.

Anyway, it turns out that having a POST through Ajax resolves the problem.

Here's what I did (in Layout view):

```
$("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 400,
                    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        //$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                        $(this).load(url);
                    },
                    buttons: [{
                        text: "Submit",
                        "class": "btn-add-properties",
                        click: function () {
                            var form = $('form', this);
                            $.post(form.prop('action'),
                                   form.serialize(),
                                   function (response) {
                                       alert("success");
                                   })
                                   .fail(function () {
                                       alert("error");
                                   });
                            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
                        }
                    }]
                });
```

The ajax post is the function under the dialog button.